# Render in JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I've got a controller with a single index action:

chat_room_controller.rb

```
class ChatRoomController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user

  def index
    @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

I need to render my variable @current_user in JSON format. So I need to create a show action or I can simply handle this situation adding:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json
end
```

I need the format JSON of this variable for reference in an AngularJS module so I also need access to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the `current_user` method to be available in your rails views, you should create a helper method in your `ApplicationController`, and then in all controllers, which inherit from it, the view will have the `current_user` helper:

```
class ApplicationController
  protected

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
  end
  helper_method :current_user
end

class ChatRoomController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: current_user
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I forgot to specify( just added ) that i need the JSON data of this variable for using it in an Angular JS module.

Comment: no need @ for current user if for juste render this.

Comment: Ok, but how can i access to @current_user data from Angular?

Comment: When you get your index url, you have the current_user object formatted in JSON.

Comment: thank you. One more thing if i need to use this variable for rails (for the tags like <%= @current_user.first_name %> in the html files) and for JSON (for use this Angular)?

Comment: I think you actually need a helper method for your rails views, and some action, which will render the `current_user` object as json.

Comment: You can't access `@current_user` from angular, because `@current_user` only lives on the server, while angular runs on the browsers. You need to serialize `@current_user` as JSON, and send it to browsers with an HTTP response.